# One Cloud Service, Two Web Sites - securing communication between the two

Tags: silverlight, azure, ssl, https, azure-web-roles

Question:  How can I communicate between two web sites using HTTPS within one Azure Cloud Service deployment?

Details:

I have architected an Azure Cloud Service deployment (one “subdomain.cloudapp.net”) in such a way as to run two separate web sites inside the deployment by using different ports.

Site 1 is what I’m calling a Service Site that is a standard ASP.NET site that hosts a bunch of WCF Services with no HTML or ASPX pages (except for a default.aspx page that redirects to site 2).  Site 1 is running on port 80.

Site 2 is my main site and hosts a Silverlight application that uses the services from Site 1 to access the database and process results.  It is only accessible by way of HTTPS and uses port 443.

Both of these sites are defined in a Visual Studio Azure solution with two endpoints, one for each port.  Further, each endpoint is associated with the two web site project insides of the VS Solution by way of the ServiceDefinition.csdef configuration file in the Azure project.

I have purchased my security certificate and associated it with a domain name that I am using with Site 2 by way of domain name redirecting and CName mapping at my DNS.

Accessing site 2 using the mapped domain name and an encrypted connection works well via HTTPS.  However, when I try to make a service call internally from Site 2 to Site 1, I am going from an HTTPS connection to an HTTP connection because I don’t have a SSL Certificate at Site 1.  As a result, when site 2 makes a service call to Site 1, it tries to serve clientaccesspolicy.xml.  This causes Internet Explorer to display the ‘Mixed Content’ message (Because of the HTTPS/HTTP mix).  Bottom line is I need to get rid of this pop-up prompt.  I know it can be disabled on the client end but with over a thousand users, I can’t depend on them being able to turn the message off.  I need to make the message go away on the server side.

Back to the question, so is there a way to access site 1 using SSL from site 2 all within the one Azure Cloud Service?  What it sounds like I need to do is assign an SSL Certificate to site 1.  However, I’m hitting two roadblocks.  First, I can’t assign an SSL Certificate to a wildcard.clouapp.net domain name.  Second, I can’t assign a second domain name to the Azure Cloud Service since I can’t do domain name forwarding to a specific port (remember that Site 2 is already using domain forwarding anyway).

I could accomplish a solution by breaking out the two sites into their own cloud services but I would rather not because it would double my cost.  Are there any suggestions on how to accomplish getting this “Mixed Content” message to go away, either by way of securing site 1 or some other method?